# removing a dictionary key if its value is null

Tags: python, dictionary

This applies to python and pandas. I have created many dictionaries from which I want to remove certain keys where its value is null.

I have tried using the following code:

```
for d in dicties:

    if d['number1'] is not None:

        d['number1'] = int(d['number1'])

for d in dicties:

    if d['number2'] is not None:

        d['number2'] = int(d['number2'])
    elif d['number2'] is None:
        del d['number2']
```

But I am getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

I am aware that the following code could be in the right direction:

```
for number2, value in list(dicties.items()):
if (value == ''):
    del dicties[key]
```

But there I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: `new_d = {k: int(v) for k, v in d.items() if v is not None}`

Answer (score 1):

It's generally easier to create a new dictionary (or list) via comprehension than to mutate the original, especially if you're iterating over the original in order to make the changes.

```
dicties = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v is not None} for d in dicties]
```

e.g.:

```
>>> dicties = [{"foo": None, "bar": 1}, {"foo": 2, "bar": None}]
>>> dicties = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v is not None} for d in dicties]
>>> dicties
[{'bar': 1}, {'foo': 2}]
>>>
```

Comment: The above is a [`dict` comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Comment: It's a dict comprehension inside a list comprehension, since they have a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```py
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v is not None}
```

Comment: This will filter out  zeroes, empty strings, etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pop:

```
d.pop('number2', None)
```

in place of:

```
del d['number2']
```